# How accurate are ipad touch points?

Tags: ios, ipad, touch

I was wondering if anybody knows how close together touch points on the ipad can be recognized. There are products like Appmates (http://www.appmatestoys.com/) that create a capacitive marker, but how close could you go / how complex markers could you create?

Moreover, I've read overall there are 10, is there a way to get around that restriction?

Comment: Depends on how many pixels wide the users finger is :)

Comment: The iPad can recognize 1 point touchers. The question is will the users be able to be accurate with their fingers.

Comment: Not with the fingers but maybe with some stylus.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this code used to find touch point in screen

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    point = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"%f,%f",point.x, point.y);


}
```